# Cannot find the "SQL Browser" service in services

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

I re-installed the OS (Windows 7) and started to install programs. After installing SQL Server, I couldn't connect to the database via Windows authentication. Then I checked for SQL Server Browser service. But I couldn't find it. What should I do now? However I want to connect with the database via windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Which error did you get?
What's the version of your SQL SERVER?

What you need to search for in the services is the SQL Server Instance, how did you name it?